Version variable not available in subsequent pipeline stages
I have set up the following pipeline (simplified) :
azure-pipelines.yml
stages:
  - stage: semanticVersioning
    ...

  - stage: build
    ...

  - stage: deployToTest
    dependsOn:
      - semanticVersioning
      - build
    ...

  - stage: deployToAcc
    dependsOn:
    # - required: semanticVersioning + build
    - deployToTest
    ...


  - stage: deployToProd
    dependsOn:
    # - required: semanticVersioning + build
    - deployToAcc
    ...

Each of the deployment stages use a build.yml template that makes use of a $(template) var defined as output in the semanticVersioning stage:
build.yml
  - stage: build
    dependsOn: semanticVersioning
    variables:
      version: $[ stageDependencies.semanticVersioning.semVer.outputs['Version.GitVersion.SemVer'] ]
...

The deployToTest stage succeeds as it depends on the semanticVersioning&build stage. I would have thought that, since deployToAcc dependsOn deployToTest, it automatically depends on the sematicVersioning and build stage as well. However, the build fails with $(version) being empty when the build.yml is invoked from the deployToAcceptance stage.
I could solve this by adding the build and semver stage to each deployment stage, but I'm curious as to why this seems necessary. Furthermore, is there a better/nicer way to ensure the variable can be reused by each of the stages?

"I could solve this by adding the build and semver stage to each deployment stage, but I'm curious as to why this seems necessary" - good question. For some reason, if you want to set a variable or condition using stageDependencies.myStage.... you need to explicitly include myStage using dependsOn.

"is there a better/nicer way to ensure the variable can be reused by each of the stages?" - probably not. Declaring a variable in each stage (like what you're doing already) is probably the simplest/best option.

Stage dependencies are only used to control the order in which stages are run and do not support inheritance of output variables.
According to Set an output variable for use in future stages,

Note the mapping syntax uses a runtime expression $[] and traces the path from stageDependencies to the output variable using both the stage name (A) and the job name (A1) to fully qualify the variable.

Explicitly specifying the stage and job that creates the output variable is by design. The pipeline relies on the path $[stageDependencies.{stage}.{job}.outputs['{taskname}.{VarName}']] to map the variable to each stage.

I do not think version: $[ stageDependencies.semanticVersioning.semVer.outputs['Version.GitVersion.SemVer'] ] can work or at least Version.GitVersion.SemVer making confusion here.
The basic format is stageDependencies.STAGE.JOB.outputs['TASK.VARIABLE'], docs, so Version.GitVersion.SemVer needs to occupy the position of task and variable, and usually this is two words here, but you have three.
Below is a sample yaml, test and worked:
pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

stages:
  - stage: semanticVersioning
    jobs:
    - job: semVer
      steps:
      - script: echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=SemVer;isOutput=true]v1"
        name: setvarStep

  - stage: build
    dependsOn: semanticVersioning
    variables:
      version: $[ stageDependencies.semanticVersioning.semVer.outputs['setvarStep.SemVer'] ]

    jobs:
    - job: build
      steps: 
      - script: echo "hello world $(version)"

  - stage: deployToTest
    dependsOn:
      - semanticVersioning
      - build
    variables:
      version: $[ stageDependencies.semanticVersioning.semVer.outputs['setvarStep.SemVer'] ]

    jobs:
    - job: deployToTestJob
      steps: 
      - script: echo "hello world $(version)"

  - stage: deployToAcc
    dependsOn:
    - deployToTest
    variables:
      version: $[ stageDependencies.semanticVersioning.semVer.outputs['setvarStep.SemVer'] ]

    jobs:
    - job: deployToAccob
      steps: 
      - script: echo "hello world $(version)"

  - stage: deployToProd
    dependsOn:
    - deployToAcc
    variables:
      version: $[ stageDependencies.semanticVersioning.semVer.outputs['setvarStep.SemVer'] ]

    jobs:
    - job: deployToProdJob
      steps: 
      - script: echo "hello world $(version)"

